# Error inserting comma separated values in Table: SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables called **'ticket'** and **'ticket_category**'.
**'Ticket'** table has a column 'Ticket_Uid' and its type is 'UniqueIdentifier'.
Each 'ticket_uid' in **'ticket'** table has one-to-many mappings in **'ticket_category'** table.
E.g.

**'Ticket' table:**

```
Ticket_Uid
100
```

**Ticket_Category:**

```
Ticket_Uid    Ticket_Category_Uid
100            ABC
100            DEF
100            XYZ
```

I want to create the following table named **'comment_mining'**:

```
Ticket_Uid    Category_List
100           ABC,DEF,XYZ
```

The table has already been created using the following:

```
create table dbo.comment_mining
(
Ticket_UID [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
time_created datetime,
time_closed datetime,
total_time_taken int,
category_list nvarchar(500),
comment_list varchar(8000)
);
```

I have already created this table and populated the 'Ticket_Uid' column.

For inserting into the 'category_list' column, I am using the following query:

```
insert into dbo.comment_mining(category_list)
SELECT 
  (SELECT distinct convert(varchar(500),category_id) + ',' AS [text()] 
   FROM ticket_category pr 
   WHERE pr.ticket_uid = p.ticket_uid 
   FOR XML PATH ('')) 
AS Category_list 
FROM comment_mining p
```

When I run the above query, it gives me the following error:

```
Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Ticket_UID', table 'Support_Saas.dbo.comment_mining'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.
```

(which is strange as I am not even inserting in the 'Ticket_Uid' column)

When I run the same query without the insert statement, it executes perfectly. The query is as follows:

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT distinct convert(varchar(500),category_id) + ',' AS [text()] 
   FROM ticket_category pr 
   WHERE pr.ticket_uid = p.ticket_uid 
   FOR XML PATH ('')) 
AS Category_list 
FROM comment_mining p
```

Yes there are some NULL values when the above query is run, but 'category_list' column in **'comment_mining'** table can take NULL values. Why is the error on 'ticket_Uid' column?

Would someone please be able to explain why this is happening and what's the cure to this?

P.S. - I am new to SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you have the insert error on table `comment_mining` is because you set the `Ticket_Uid` column as `not null`; however, since it does not have a default value, the insert fails because *whether you're inserting that field specifically or not*, when a row is created, all columns must be filled in or be `null`.

**You can do one of 2 things:**

---

- Change the structure of the `comment_mining` table to have a `default` value for `Ticket_Uid` (You can do this in the table designer or with code:

*Example 1:*

```
Alter Table comment_mining 
    Add Constraint DF_CommentMining_1 default NewID() for Ticket_UID
```

---

- Make your insert explicitly include a generated `uniqueidentifier` (GUID) value by using the SQL `NewID()` function to populate the Ticket_UID `UniqueIdentifier` column

*Example 2:*

```
insert into dbo.comment_mining(Ticket_Uid, category_list)
SELECT NewID(), 
   [ your subquery ]...
```

---

In both cases, you're now satisfying the `NOT NULL` constraint on `comment_mining.Ticket_UID`, either by making it automatically populate itself, or by supplying a value.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just figured it out. You're absolutely right. When I removed the constraint from ticket_uid, I was able to insert properly.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
;with cte as
(    
select 100 Ticket_Uid,'ABC' Ticket_Category_Uid union all
select 100 , 'DEF' union all
select 100, 'XYZ' 
) 

select distinct b.Ticket_Uid,
stuff((select ','+a.Ticket_Category_Uid from cte a where a.Ticket_Uid=b.Ticket_Uid for xml path('')),1,1,'')

from cte b
```